# Heroku node.js app 'allocation failure scavenge might not succeed' with memory still available

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, heap-memory, dyno

I'm getting heap memory errors that crash my app. But my app has memory available.

```
 app/web.1 [4:0x4ea2840]    27490 ms: Mark-sweep 505.7 (522.4) -> 502.2 (523.1) MB, 440.3 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.280, current mu = 0.148) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
```

```
app/web.1 FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

The error happens around 512mb. My  standard-2X dyno has 1gb.

Node version is 16.17.0. As far as I understand, heap limits for node versions over 12 are based on available memory.

> Versions of Node that are >= 12 may not need to use the --optimize_for_size and --max_old_space_size flags because the JavaScript heap limit will be based on available memory.
> [src](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-memory-use#tuning-the-garbage-collector)

I considered the one worker on a 512mb dyno. But would a worker dyno cause the whole app to crash? And if that were the case wouldn't the error come from `app/worker.1` and not `app/web.1` like is shown in the logs?

## UPDATE

I figured out how to recreate the heap limit Allocation Error. This allowed me to get some more clues.

I get the error at around **256mb** on a **512mb hobby dyno**.

I get the error at around **512mb** on a **1024mb(1gb) standard 2X**.

So it's always half the available memory. I'm not sure if this is some sort of setting on heroku.

### UPDATE 2

Using the v8 node module (included in node) I could get more data:

```js
const v8 = require('v8');
```

```js
   // added the code below to a route that caused a memory leak
   const heapStats = v8.getHeapStatistics();
    const heapStatsMB = heapStats;
    for (const key in heapStatsMB) {
      heapStatsMB[key] = `${(((heapStatsMB[key] / 1024 / 1024) * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)} MB`;
    }

    console.table(heapStatsMB);
```

I could see the `heap_size_limit` was 259 on a hobby dyno and 515 on a 2X standard dyno.

```
   ┌─────────────────────────────┬─────────────┐
   │           (index)           │   Values    │
   ├─────────────────────────────┼─────────────┤
   │       total_heap_size       │ '268.08 MB' │
   │ total_heap_size_executable  │  '2.25 MB'  │
   │     total_physical_size     │ '266.73 MB' │
   │    total_available_size     │  '3.31 MB'  │
   │       used_heap_size        │ '263.69 MB' │
   │       heap_size_limit       │ '259.00 MB' │
   │       malloced_memory       │  '1.01 MB'  │
   │    peak_malloced_memory     │  '3.03 MB'  │
   │      does_zap_garbage       │  '0.00 MB'  │
   │  number_of_native_contexts  │  '0.00 MB'  │
   │ number_of_detached_contexts │  '0.00 MB'  │
   │  total_global_handles_size  │  '0.16 MB'  │
   │  used_global_handles_size   │  '0.16 MB'  │
   │       external_memory       │ '18.53 MB'  │
   └─────────────────────────────┴─────────────┘
```

Comment: Which buildpack are you using?

Comment: @Lissy93 when i run `heroku buildpacks --app myapp` i get `myapp Buildpack URL
heroku/nodejs`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### TLDR:

`--max-old-space-size=1024` goes in the procfile.

```
web: node --max-old-space-size=1024 bin/www
```

or

Add an environment variable key: `NODE_OPTIONS` with a value of `--max_old_space_size=1024`

### Details

Originally my Procfile was

```
web: node --optimize_for_size  bin/www
```

And I had an environment variable key of `--max-old-space-size` with value `1024`.

This was not the right way to list the environment variable. It should be key: `NODE_OPTIONS` with a value of `--max_old_space_size=1024`. I haven't tried this yet myself.

Instead I changed my procfile to:

```
web: node --optimize_for_size --max-old-space-size=1024 bin/www
```

which also works.

I'm not sure `--optimize_for_size` does anything because `node bin/www` vs `node --optimize_for_size bin/www` both changed the `heap_size_limit` to around the same amount based on the dyno size. So later I took `--optimize_for_size` out.